# How to round up in postgres

Tags: postgresql, rounding

I have a list of schools with numbers of how many student there are for the 8th grade, I need to add an extra field where I can add 10% ontop of the total student number and rounded upwards. However it doesnt round up it rounds down.

E.g. 51 students
51/10 = 5.1
this value needs to be rounded up to 6 not 5

what am I missing exactly? Am i even rounding up because the value from count is an integer?

[image]

```
select *, (studentcount + (studentcount/10)) as roundup
from ( 
     select sch.SchoolID as sid, sch.Schoolname as sn, count(distinct s.studentid) as studentcount
     from student s
     join studentschool ss on ss.studentid=s.studentid
     join school sch on sch.id = ss.schoolid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `ceil` ([function math doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-math.html))

> `ceil`: nearest integer greater than or equal to argument

```
select *, ceil(studentcount + (studentcount/10)) as roundup
from ...
```

Comment: i was correct about the values not being float, however your function is correct.